# Global Address List in Outlook 2011 for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, address-book, microsoft-outlook-2011

We manage our employee contact info inside the Exchange 2007 global address list (addresses, phone numbers, etc) and are looking for how to access that info in Outlook 2011 on OS X.  I can't seem to find *anywhere* that Outlook can access this data from the Exchange Server except in the the "To:" box address autofill when drafting an email or calendar appointment.  This functionality is handy, but I'd *really* like a way to search the GAL for users' contact cards to get their cell numbers and whatnot.

Is there a way to do this that I haven't found?  It's pretty unreasonable to me to manage this separately and have each user have to keep current contact records in their own personal Outlook address books - kinda defeats the purpose of the GAL...

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get the Exchange address book added to your list of address books in outlook from your "Account Settings" window, selecting Add Address Book and choosing LDAP.

GAL integration works in Outlook for OSX through LDAP.

More compatibility information here:

http://blog.aaronmarks.com/?p=42

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can search the Global Address list by going to the Contacts interface and either clicking "Contacts Search" in the toolbar or just typing your query in the search box immediately above that.

I would prefer to show all of the names in the GAL in that interface, instead of having to search, but this appears to be missing from Outlook for Mac 2011.